# Event Object Does not Show a Lookup Field even though the field is in the page layout

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I created a custom object and created a lookup field on Activity(Event) object to the custom object. I added the lookup field to the Event object page layout, but it is not showing up. Weirdly, the lookup field to other custom object is showing up on Event object.

I have checked my profile and confirmed the object is visible.
Where else I can check?
If someone can help me I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Did you check both the Lookup field permission AND the referenced object permissions?

Comment: Check the field access on Lookup field and referenced object. 
Also check the layout assignment if any, to see if field is present in correct layout.

Comment: I checked all of them. And I just recreated the lookup field and it solved the issue....